# Why is document.anchors command not using first link as the index 0 instead of the second link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_anchors.asp
it should target first link at index 0 but it is setting the attribute of second link instead of first. Why is this happening?!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p id="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" id="blank">Anchor</a>
  <a name="html">HTML Tutorial</a><br>

  <script>
  
jQuery(window).on("load",function() {
    alert('Hi');
    
    //Set the TEXT, add an ATTRIBUTE, added a CLASS.
    //Returns the wrapper set 
    $('#blank').text('I was inserted here to go to Google').attr({'href':'https://www.google.com','second':'attr'}).addClass('Added_class');

    $('<p id ="para"></p>').appendTo('body');
    $(document.createElement('a')).text('jQuery').attr({'id':'anchor','href':'https://www.google.com'}).appendTo('#para');

    $(document.anchors[0]).attr('hey', 'value');
});
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: [_"For reasons of backwards compatibility, the returned set of anchors only contains those anchors created with the name attribute, not those created with the id attribute."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/anchors#Notes)